# Crystal Reports 2011: Calculate the number of times a value occures and the number of days in between

Tags: crystal-reports, datediff

It occurs to me that I might have been able to find the answer to this but so far i've come up short. Also, I am pretty new to Crystal Reports (2011) so please forgive my ignorance if this is something I've missed. Here's the issue:

I have a report where I am pulling the number of times a value happens for a specific target, specifically how many times a specific procedure happens for a person within a specified date range. I have the results grouped by person.

I show the person, the procedure code and the date the procedure happend within that group.

What I NEED to do now, is to figure out how to return some type of visual indicator that there is at least 3 days in between each procedure for each person.. example..

[**GROUP #1 NAME**]....................[**PROC_CODE**]......[**PROC_DATE**]

[{Last_Name}, {First_Name}].....PROCEDURE..........PROCEDURE DATE

(Please forgive the "....." as I was trying to space out the headers and results)

Having said all that, the "Procedure Date" I would like to show up in RED if the next result within the group (by person) falls within 3 or less days from the last date. I am really hoping this makes sense to someone. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a formula called "DateDiff": `DateDiff("d", {Proc_Date}, previous({Proc_Date}))`

then in your Section Expert, choose the group that your data is in. Click the color tab. Choose the "x-2" formula button and enter: `if {@DateDiff} > 3 then crred else crnocolor`

edit so your next group doesnt pick up the last value:

```
if ({group1_field} = previous({group1_field})) then
 if {@DateDiff} > 3 then crred else crnocolor
else
crnocolor
```

Comment: I get an error when attempting to create the second formula stating that the formula cannot be used because it must be evaluated later. It makes me think it's because it's based on a parameter field? (the date field)?

Comment: Never mind, it totally worked. You are a genius!! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: So after all that, this is NEARLY perfect! I have one problem i'm hoping you can help out with (again)... So based on the grouping and the dates, it does work. However... if the first date on the next group is earlier than the last date on the previous group, the first date will appear red. Is there a way to make the first returned value ignore the last returned value of the previous group? I would LOVE to attach a screenshot but I don't see where I can do that when adding a comment.

Comment: try my edited answer..{group1_field} being whatever field you are grouping by in group 1.

Comment: So, it appears that we're on the cusp of figuring this out. The lingering issue that I'm having, is that the datediff is not ignoring the last date of the group results before it (if that makes any sense). What i'm seeing, is that if the date of the final value from the previous group is 5/10/2016 and the first date of the next group value is 5/26/2016, the datediff doesn't ignore those differences, and results a huge disparity between what it should be ignoring (i.e... an integer of 16, or 16 days difference). So how can we tell the first group result to not calcluate on the prior group?

Comment: What field are you grouping by? Do you just have one group?

Comment: It works, actually perfect. I had to change the sort order to descending so that the most current date would appear first. This allowed the DateDiff to not return a negative integer. Thank you so much again, especially for being so helpful and patient with me. On that note, i'd like to ask a more advanced question if you've got the time?